# How to query according to an specific document matching criteria inside an array in a MongoDB doc?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection `lineups` which got the `players` attribute being an array, players looks like this:

```
{
    players: [{id: "ac52", points: 24, captain: false}, {id: "as4f", points: 15, captain:true}]
}
```

How can I find *those lineups with a document with id: `ac52` and `points` distinct of 24 inside `players` array attribute?*

I know and have used `$elemMatch` but in this case I don't only need to find those inside array with a document with `id` *something* but a set of attribute matching a criteria.

So, for example if I have this set of documents:

```
{
    players: [{id: "ac52", points: 24, captain: false}, {id: "as4f", points: 15, captain:true}]
}

{
    players: [{id: "ac52", points: 26, captain: false}, {id: "as4f", points: 15, captain:true}]
}

{
    players: [{id: "ac52", points: 11, captain: false}, {id: "as4f", points: 15, captain:true}]
}
```

I'd need my query to output:

```
{
    players: [{id: "ac52", points: 26, captain: false}, {id: "as4f", points: 15, captain:true}]
}

{
    players: [{id: "ac52", points: 11, captain: false}, {id: "as4f", points: 15, captain:true}]
}
```

### Edit:

I've tried with:

```
db.lineup.count({"matchDate.round": 6, $and: [{players: {$elemMatch: {id: "p106212", currentRoundPoints: {$ne: 8}}}}, {players: {$elemMatch: {id: "p106212", currentRoundPoints: {$ne: 16}}}}]})
```

Getting not expected results

Comment: Can you show the expected result?

Comment: Updated with expected result @user3100115

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the `lineups` docs that contain a `players` element with an `id` of `'ac52'` and `points` something besides `24` you can combine both those clauses in a single `$elemMatch`:

```js
db.lineups.find({
    players: {$elemMatch: {
        id: 'ac52',
        points: {$ne: 24}
    }}
})
```